# Disable delete key in terminal prompt

Tags: terminal

I modified my prompt in my `.bashrc` file using the following command:

```
PS1='\[$(tput bold)\e[1;34m\w\e[m$ '
```

Now my prompt shows the current directory in bold blue color followed by the `$` sign. On a new prompt, **if no other text has been entered**, I press the delete key **nothing happens**.

However, if I enter any text, say `cd`, delete that and then press the delete key once more, it will delete my prompt. How can I change my `.bashrc` file so my prompt can never be deleted?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bash is confused about how long your prompt actually is. You can tell bash by enclosing non-printable parts of the prompt with backslash-brackets: \[....\].
Your prompt, however only contains the opening bracket, making bash believe that the prompt is very short, so it happily removes almost all of it in some situations. A proper use of the bracketing would look like this:

```
PS1='\[$(tput bold)\e[1;34m\]\w\[\e[m\]$ '
```

That is, everything is in backslash-bracket except the working directory and the dollar sign, because those are the only parts that actually consume space on the terminal screen.